# Use of "from where looking to"

Tags: word-choice

.....(Name of the Town), which may become the panoramic spot from where **looking to/at** Gran Sasso *(mountain)* and the valley in which the village is situated.

Comment: This sentence seems unfinished... I'm expecting a **will**

Comment: It's like.. *We will build this tower from where looking at the valley will allow us to see all the harvesters currently working.*

Comment: And It's **Look at**. **"look to"** means *"to direct your thoughts or attention to something"*, *"to rely on someone or something"*, *"To expect or hope for something"* or *"to expect someone or something to supply something"*

Comment: The whole sentence is a little awkward to me.... Perhaps just saying, ".....(Name of the Town), which has potential to be *a* panoramic spot 
*for* viewing (looking at) Gran Sasso and the valley in which the village is situated.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is awkward

> .(Name of the Town), which may become the panoramic spot from where **looking to/at** Gran Sasso (mountain) and the valley in which the village is situated.

"from where" is redundant since you already have said "the..spot".

Better might be

> (Name of the Town), which may become the panoramic spot *for* **looking towards/at** Gran Sasso (mountain) and the valley in which the village is situated.

From a panoramic or *beauty spot*, one usually

> looks out
>   looks towards
>   looks at

a view.